# How to use git filter-branch on pattern of folders

Tags: bash, git, git-filter-branch

I've committed a bunch of sensitive data to my local repo that has not been published yet.

The sensitive data is scattered across the project in different folders and I want to remove all these completely from git history.

All of the concerning folders have the same name, and are at the same level in the directory in different folders. Following is a sample of my folder structure:

```
root
    folder1
           ./sensitiveData
    folder2
           ./sensitiveData
    folder3
           ./sensitiveData
```

using the following command, I am able to delete the folders containing sensitive data one at a time:

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch javascript/folder1/.sensitiveData' --prune-empty HEAD
```

But I want to delete all the folders containing sensitive data in one go, because, they are too many, and I would like to learn how this works.

But using the following command, nothing is rewritten and I am warned that `'refs/heads/master' is unchanged` is unchanged:

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch javascript/*/.sensitiveData' --prune-empty HEAD
```

As I see it, there are two strategies:

1. Either my pattern is somehow wrong and I need to change it.
2. Or I should do some looping with bash.

Option one seems more sensible if possible.

Comment: Instead of one-liner you seems need a full script where you do whatever you want to.

Comment: so the `*` does not expand in this context?

Comment: I dunno, but even if it does, with a lot of folders you may have too long command line. This approach is initially wrong.

Comment: The addresses are relative so it won't go deeper than the three levels that you see in the commands.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the end, what solved my problem was a small bash script using the `for in` construct.

```sh
for name in javascript/*/.sensitiveData
    do git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch $name" --prune-empty HEAD
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Your command, when you run it, is first evaluated by your shell.  So with:

```
'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch javascript/*/.sensitiveData'
```

the single quotes protect the entire thing from the shell, and pass it to `git filter-branch` as the `--index-filter` to be used later.  The single quotes are gone at this point.

Here's the problem: filters given to `git filter-branch` get evaluated at filtering-time by *another shell* (technically, the shell that's running `git filter-branch` itself).  This other shell `eval`s the command:

```
eval $filter
```

So now this second shell re-interprets:

```
git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch javascript/*/.sensitiveData
```

It breaks up the arguments at spaces, *expands the asterisk based on the current working directory*, and invokes `git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatched` on the result of the expansion.

If the expansion succeeds, one thing happens; if not, something else happens.  Precisely what happens depends on the shell (bash can be configured to behave in several different ways; POSIX `sh` is more predictable).

The actual current working directory for an `--index-filter` is generally empty so the expansion will probably fail.  This should, in *most* cases, pass the asterisk on unchanged to Git.  Since the argument to `git rm` is (mostly / essentially) a *pathspec*, Git will now do its own expansion.  This should have worked, so either the path itself is wrong, or the directory is not empty, or there's something odd about your shell so that the failed expansion didn't pass the literal text `javascript/*/.sensitiveData` to `git rm`.

You can take some variables out of this equation by using:

```
'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch javascript/\*/.sensitiveData'
```

so that the second shell sees:

```
git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch javascript/\*/.sensitiveData
```

which will force the second shell to pass:

```
javascript/*/.sensitiveData
```

directly to `git rm`.  Given that this probably should have worked anyway, though, it's of interest to check whether `javascript/*/.sensitiveData` would match the right files in the specific commit(s), which you can do kind of clumsily / manually using `git ls-tree -r` on those commits.

Comment: thanks @torek for your thorough answer. I escaped the asterisk `\*` and it didn't help. I also ran the command `git ls-tree -r javascript/*/.sensitiveData` as you suggested and got the following error `fatal: Not a valid object name javascript/folder1/.sensitiveData` which seems to indicate that the pattern here is at least working. Any thoughts?

Comment: `git ls-tree -r` needs a *commit hash ID* argument. the idea here was to look at one of the commits from which you want these files removed, to make sure that `javascript/*/.sensitiveData` should match all the files. So let's say that one of the commits with the files you want gone is `a123456`; use `git ls-tree -r a123456` and eyeball the output.

Comment: thanks @torek I just went with another solution using bash (and learned some bash along the way). It's a simple `for in` but it worked perfectly. Already learned a lot from your answer. Will check `git ls-tree`. Thanks again :D